# Removing the largest variance from a group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

If I have a set of objects each with the same description, but with different amounts.

```
{

    {
    "_id": "101",
    "description": "DD from my employer1",
    "amount": 1000.33
    },
    {
    "_id": "102",
    "description": "DD from my employer1",
    "amount": 1000.34
    },
    {
    "_id": "103",
    "description": "DD from my employer1",
    "amount": 999.35
    },
    {
    "_id": "104",
    "description": "DD from my employer1"",
    "amount": 5000.00
    },
    {
    "_id": "105",
    "description": "DD from my employer2",
    "amount": 2000.01
    },
    {
    "_id": "106",
    "description": "DD from my employer2",
    "amount": 1999.33
    },
    {
    "_id": "107",
    "description": "DD from my employer2",
    "amount": 1999.33
    }

}
```

Below, I am able to group them using the following:

```
{
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$subtract": [
                {
                    "$trunc": "$amount"
                },
                {
                    "$mod": [
                        {
                            "$trunc": "$amount"
                        },
                        10
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "results": {
            "$push": "$_id"
        }
    }
},
{
    "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": {
                "$gt": [
                    {
                        "$size": "$results"
                    },
                    1
                ]
            },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }
},
{
    "$unwind": "$results"
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "results": {
            "$push": "$results"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Is there a way to include all the amounts in the group (_ids: 101, 102, and 103 plus 105,106,107) even if they have a small difference, but exclude the bonus amount, which in the sample above as _id 104?

I am looking for a simple array output of just the _ids.

Looking for the following result:

```
{ "result": [ "101", "102", "103", "105", "106", "107" ] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's all a bit subjective to the actual data, but if it's simply about a significant "positive" difference to the "average" payment then that is the best algorithm to apply:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$description",
    "avg": { "$avg": "$amount" },
    "docs": { "$push": { "_id": "$_id", "amount": "$amount" } }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "docs": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$docs",
        "as": "doc",
        "cond": {
          "$gt": [ "$avg", { "$subtract": [ "$$doc.amount", "$avg" ] } ]
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$docs" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "results": { "$push": "$docs._id" }
  }}
])
```

From your given data this would exclude the `"104"` amount since the difference from the amount to the average amounts from "employer 1" is greater than the average itself. This will be the case for a large "upwards" variation.

As with all "grouping" methods that rely on creating an array within the grouped document, you need to be careful in real world scenarios to not break the BSON limit.